# Portable Twitter clients?

Tags: portable, twitter

Are there any good Twitter clients for Windows that can run on a thumb drive?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Pwytter Portable](http://portableapps.com/node/13317). It is a easy to use and light weight twitter client. My only criticism of the program is that it does not provide any sort of notification of new tweets if the window is not focused.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best will be portable browser.

Firefox is in portable version and you could install Power Twitter addon (which I use)

Answer (score 0):

[**Pidgin**](http://www.pidgin.im/) allows you to log in to multiple networks together.
There is a [**PortableApp** edition for Pidgin](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/pidgin_portable).

**And** for Twitter,
there is a [**Pidgin plugin** (**microblog-purple**)](http://code.google.com/p/microblog-purple/) that supports
[**Twitter**](http://twitter.com/), [Identica](http://identi.ca/), and [Laconica-base server](http://laconi.ca/) through the conversation windows

This should let you use Twitter from your thumbdrive,
and maybe even across Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[Portable Digsby](http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/portable-digsby-build-67/) supports Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try echofon.

it's a firefox extension
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/echofon-for-twitter/

previously twitterfox project. but now echofon. seems promising